# Spring boot App not working after ssh logout

Tags: java, linux, spring, maven, ssh

So I'm deploying my Spring Boot application on an Ubuntu LTS Server. It is built with maven and running with embedded Tomcat.

I'm still new to the deployment process, what I did was:

1. Log into server via ssh
2. use scp to upload my_application.zip
3. unzip it in ssh
4. java -jar my_application.jar

Now all of that works perfectly fine and I've been using it like that for quiet some time. Now I have to make the Application to stay online and available after logging out of the shell.

I have read some documentation about running processes in background on Linux and I've tried it with `nohup java -jar myApplication.jar &`, with the `screen` command and with `bg`. All of them worked fine while I'm logged into the ssh.

Here comes my problem:

As soon as I end the ssh session the Web App is still available (so the process clearly didn't stop) but it just looks & behaves really weird.
CSS is not applied, JS does not work etc.

My guess would be that some paths or file system accesses are messed up, but I have no idea at all how that could origin from the ssh session.

(When I log back into ssh everything is working fine again)

Would be great if someone has a clue here

Comment: Do you have encrypted home?

Comment: If you're asking if i use SSL then yes, i have configured the app on SSL and standard SSL port 8443.

Comment: No. I am asking if you have configured your Ubuntu to have encrypted home of the user you are connecting to.

Comment: Yes I have, good point. I will try it out in an unencrypted dir!

Comment: Seems to work in an now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server has encrypted home directory, it will get re-encrypted once you log out and therefore your script will stop working. It does not have a lot of sense to have encrypted homes on servers so you can disable it.

Or just run the script from different directory and avoid working with files under home directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `systemd` for this case.
Also You can add new system user for your app.
You can find more information here:

[Spring Boot: 59.2.2 Installation as a systemd service](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-systemd-service)

[Ubuntu Wiki: Systemd For UpstartUsers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers)

For example:
Create file `myunit.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=MySpringService
After=syslog.target
After=network.target
After=mysql.service

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/work/www/myunit/shared/tmp/pids/service.pid
WorkingDirectory=/work/www/myunit/current

User=myunit
Group=myunit

Environment=RACK_ENV=production

OOMScoreAdjust=-1000

ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/bundle exec service -C /work/www/myunit/shared/config/service.rb --daemon
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/bundle exec service -S /work/www/myunit/shared/tmp/pids/service.state stop
ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/bundle exec service -S /work/www/myunit/shared/tmp/pids/service.state restart
TimeoutSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Copy file to `/etc/systemd/system/`
Run:
`systemctl enable myunit`
`systemctl start myunit`